# Подключение по ssh при сборке в Jenkins (Host key verification failed.)

Tags: linux, ssh, jenkins

Создал item в Jenkins, который должен выполнить bash скрипт подключение к виртуальной машине:

```
ssh user@192.168.100.100 'ls'
```

При выполнении, получаю ошибку:

```
Host key verification failed.
```

При этом добавил ключ ssh в Manage Credentials / Global credentials, указав ключ, id и username

Сам ключ генерировал на машине 192.168.100.100 с помощью ssh-keygen и использовал id_rsa

Но ошибку победить так и не смог, подскажите, куда смотреть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решить вопрос внутри интерфейса Jenkins у меня не получилось, пришлось воспользоваться консолью:

На основной машине, где установлен дженкинс:

```
sudo -i #Переход под root пользователя
su - jenkins #Вход под пользователем jenkins
ssh-keygen #Создаем ключ ssh
nano .ssh/id_rsa.pub # Копируем полученный ключ
```

Подключаемся на виртуальную машину и вставляем скопированный ключ в файл `.ssh/authorized_keys`

Возвращаемся на основную машину, переходим под пользователя Дженкинс и подключаемся через ssh к виртуальной машине, подтверждаем подключение ( `yes` ) и все готово